# How can I force the creation of an object declared in the resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am declaring an object in XAML (in my UserControl.Resources section) as follows:

```
<vm:ErrorDisplayService x:Key="EDSvc"/>
```

The constructor of my object is not being called.

I am able to get it to work if I put a dummy object in like this:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Text={StaticResource EDSvc}/>
```

but this seems to be a hack to me.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

JAB

Comment: i've had this problem before, and it is usually a result of either the resource class missing a default, parameterless constructor, or something wrong with the order in which i instantiate objects inside that class... the resources should all be loaded when the first page navigates; if they dont you very likely have a bug in your control